# Как в Text View импортировать данные из iCloud, если в iCloud записи имеют тип String(List)

Tags: массивы, swift, строки, textview, облако

В *iCloud* есть база данных `TectDB`.

В `TectDB` есть таблица с полем `String(List)`.

В программе есть `TableViewController`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как в `TextView` импортировать данные из `String(List)`?

Следующий код не работает:

```
(cell.textView.text = record.object(forKey: "ListStr") as! String

Ошибка: Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x1ab9a57a0) to 
'NSString' (0x1ab9b5ae8).
2017-09-15 14:53:27.322654+0800 Cloud[2335:931930] Could not cast value of 
type '__NSArrayM' (0x1ab9a57a0) to 'NSString' (0x1ab9b5ae8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. На сколько оно правильное не знаю, но сработало.
Может у вас есть более изящное решение?

```
let ListStr:[String] = (record.object(forKey: "ListStr") as!
NSMutableArray) as! [String]
let Str = ListStr.joined(separator: "\n")
cell.textView.text = Str
```

В `let Str = ListStr.joined(separator: "n\")` можно использовать спецсимволы. Например: "\n" будет переводить на новую строку в тексте.